# Sublime Build system for c++ in linux allowing input from file

Tags: c++, linux, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using sublime in linux I am trying to compile and run my c++ program from sublime directly with INPUT taken from a file rather than STDIN.
Please help me with the code to be written in sublime build-file.
I got this code but its not working i think its for windows not for linux:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["g++", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
    "variants": [
        {   
            "cmd": ["${file_base_name}" , "<" , "input.txt"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run",
            "working_dir" : "$file_path"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the final code which one needs to write in build system of sublime to compile and run taking input from a file.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++ -Wall ${file} -o ${file_base_name}"], 
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",

    "variants": [
                {   
                    "cmd": [ "${file_path}/${file_base_name}<input.txt"],
                    "shell": true,
                    "name": "Run",
                    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
                }
            ]
}
```

Thanks a lot MattDMo.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason it's not working is because `g++` is creating a `.exe` file, and the build system is only looking for the `source.c` scope, whereas your code may be `source.c++`. Change the first two lines to the following:

```
"cmd" : ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c, source.c++",
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: I am getting this in the console:  


    g++: fatal error: no input files    
    compilation terminated.  
    [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 4]  
    [cmd: ['g++', 'main2.cpp', '-o', 'main2']]  
    [dir: /home/shikhar/CP/work]  
    [path:     /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]

Comment: @sv_jan5 what happens if you run the same command from Terminal? Switch to `~/CP/work` and run `g++ main2.cpp -o main2`.

Comment: This command in terminal is giving executable file named 'main2'. There is no problem with compiler.

Comment: @sv_jan5 See my edit above. I suspect that `g++` is looking for the file in the wrong directory, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add a config I use to load input from the file and display output in Sublime console ("Run in") or send output to other file ("Run in out"). Maybe someone will find it useful. (works for both Windows and Ubuntu)

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run in",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" <$file_base_name.in"
    },
    {
        "name": "Run in out",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" <$file_base_name.in >$file_base_name.txt"
    }
]
}
```